# Dockerfile mkdir permission denied

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I am trying to build the image with:

```
docker build -t db-demo .
```

But i get

> RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app:
> #5 0.512 mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/src/app': Permission denied

The Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh
ENV SA_PASSWORD bpassword
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_PID Express
EXPOSE 1433

CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

The OS  is Windows.How to fix this?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say: the active user in the image is not `root`, and the active user has no access right to `/usr/src`. We can [change the active user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) to `root`, create the directory we need, give the other user (which we have to identify first, e.g. by a `RUN whoami` or by executing `whoami` in a container running the base image) permission to `/usr/src/app` and then change back to the non-root user.

Comment: Unrelated question: what should be `COPY`ed to `/usr/src/app`?

Answer (score 9):

If we start the `mssql` container with an interactive shell:

```
docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server /bin/bash
```

and then look at the active user within the container:

```
mssql@ed73727870bb:/$ whoami
mssql
```

we see that the active user is `mssql`. Furthermore, if we look at the permissions for `/usr/src` inside the container:

```
mssql@ed73727870bb:/$ ls -lisa /usr | grep -i src
163853 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 15  2020 src
```

we see that only `root` has write-access to directory `/usr/src`.

Thus, if we want to create a directory `/usr/src/app`, so that user `mssql` can write to it, we will have to

- create it as `root` and
- grant the appropriate permissions to `mssql`.

This leads to the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server

# change active user to root
USER root 

# create the app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# set mssql as owner of the app directory
RUN chown mssql /usr/src/app

# change back to user mssql
USER mssql

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# sanity check: try to write a file
RUN echo "Hello from user mssql" > hello.txt
```

if we build and run this `Dockerfile`:

```
docker build -t turing85/my-mssql -f Dockerfile .
docker run -it --rm turing85/my-mssql /bin/bash
```

We can now see that:

- the active user is still `mssql`:

  ```
  mssql@85e401ccc3f9:/usr/src/app$ whoami
  mssql
  ```
- a file `/usr/src/app/hello.txt` has been created, and user `mssql` has read-access:

  ```
  mssql@85e401ccc3f9:/usr/src/app$ cat hello.txt
  Hello from user mssql
  ```
- user `mssql` has write-access to `/usr/src/app`:

  ```
  mssql@85e401ccc3f9:/usr/src/app$ touch test.txt && ls -lisa
  total 16
  171538 4 drwxr-xr-x 1 mssql root 4096 Nov  6 20:13 .
  171537 8 drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root 4096 Nov  6 20:02 ..
  171539 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 mssql root   17 Nov  6 20:02 hello.txt
  171604 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 mssql root    0 Nov  6 20:13 test.txt
  ```
- user `mssql` has no write-access to `/usr/src`:

  ```
  mssql@85e401ccc3f9:/usr/src/app$ touch ../test2.txt
  touch: cannot touch '../test2.txt': Permission denied
  ```

---

A comment on the `Dockerfile` in the post:

It seems that we try to copy an application into the `mssql` container. I assume this is done to start said application within the `mssql` container. While this is possible (with some configuration), I strongly advice against this approach. We could instead define two containers (one for the database, one for the application), e.g. through a [`docker-compose` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/).

Comment: i must say this is a brilliant af answer. i had an issue with sqlite permissions in data directory. i didn't know how to use mkdir with chown but your solution & explanation is on point.

Answer (score 1):

`WORKDIR` creates the named directory if it doesn't exist.  If your only permission problem is while trying to create the directory, you can remove the `RUN mkdir` line and let Docker create the directory for you.

```sh
FROM any-base-image
# Docker creates the directory if it does not exist
# You do not need to explicitly RUN mkdir
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
...
```

Looking further at this example, the `RUN chmod ...` line might also fail if the base image has a non-root user that can't access a root-owned directory.  `COPY` will also copy the permissions from the host, so if the file is executable in the host environment you would not need to explicitly `chmod +x` it after it is `COPY`ed in.  That would let you delete all of the `RUN` lines; you'd be left with `COPY` and `ENV` instructions and runtime metadata, none of which should encounter permission problems.